# OS X command line installer track progress

Tags: macos, bash, pkg

I am trying to install an application through command line in OS X. This is what I am trying:

```
hdiutil attach app.dmg
cd /Volumes/appvolume
installer -pkg app.pkg -target "/"
```

This works fine, however, I am not able to get an output from the `installer` command from which I can capture the amount of progress made and the time/amount remaining. I tried the `verbose` option

```
installer -verbose -pkg app.pkg -target "/"
```

But this only prints output like **installer: Optimizing system for installed software….....**, etc, nothing about progress. But it surely knows about progress, because when I install the app via double clicking, the installer window that pops up shows a deterministic progress bar that progresses gradually and reaches full length when installation is complete.

Any way I can capture the progress status through command line `installer` as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close - the option you're looking for is -verbose**R**:

```
Usage: installer [-help] [-dominfo] [-volinfo] [-pkginfo] [-allowUntrusted] [-dumplog]
             [-verbose | -verboseR] [-vers] [-config] [-plist]
             [-file <pathToFile>] [-lang <ISOLanguageCode>] [-listiso]
             [-showChoicesXML] [-applyChoiceChangesXML <pathToFile>]
             [-showChoicesAfterApplyingChangesXML <pathtoFile>]
             -pkg <pathToPackage>
             -target <[DomainKey|MountPoint]
```

Here's `installer`'s output installing a Firefox 43.0.1 .pkg built with [AutoPkgr](https://github.com/lindegroup/autopkgr) with that flag:

```
timmay:~ da4$ sudo installer -pkg /Users/da4/Desktop/auto/Firefox-43.0.1.pkg -target / -verboseR
installer: Package name is Firefox-43.0.1
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer:PHASE:Preparing for installation…
installer:PHASE:Preparing the disk…
installer:PHASE:Preparing Firefox-43.0.1…
installer:PHASE:Waiting for other installations to complete…
installer:PHASE:Configuring the installation…
installer:STATUS:
installer:%9.883908
installer:PHASE:Writing files…
installer:%30.674055
installer:PHASE:Writing files…
installer:%51.530939
installer:PHASE:Optimizing system for installed software…
installer:PHASE:Validating packages…
installer:PHASE:Validating packages…
installer:%97.750000
installer:STATUS:
installer:PHASE:Finishing the Installation…
installer:STATUS:
installer:%100.000000
installer:PHASE:The software was successfully installed.
installer: The upgrade was successful.
timmay:~ da4$
```

I'm not exactly sure when the -verboseR option was added to OS X's installer, but it's present in 10.9+.

Comment: Thanks. While we are at it, can you suggest a way for me to capture the output number whenever the percentage is shown? Say whenever the line `installer:%9.883908` comes along, I want to capture the `9` part and echo it instantly (and suppressing the original output supposed to be given by `verboseR`). Probably I need to use `grep`, I cannot figure out how. That is, the output of my command will be `9`, then `30`, then `51`, etc..

Comment: If you wanted to grab the entire percentage, you could use sed: `grep % | sed 's/installer:%//g` - if you wanted to only capture to whole integer, you'd probably have better luck with `awk`

Comment: Problem is the Mac does not come with GNU sed, so I cannot rely on sed. OSX's version of sed is clumsy..

Comment: How so?  `timmay:~ da4$ sudo installer -pkg /Users/da4/Desktop/auto/Firefox-43.0.1.pkg -target / -verboseR | grep % | sed 's/installer:%//g'
7.573892
28.364039
46.844170
95.628934
97.262500
97.750000
100.000000`

Comment: Lemme try it out then..

Comment: Umm, it worked, but not in the way I was expecting it to. It waited for a long time before spitting out any output, and when it did, it immediately outputted `5.30`, `8.12`, etc. unto `100.0` immediately in one go. I did not want this, I wanted `5.30` to come when indeed 5.30 percentage was complete..

Comment: I can do it through `awk`: `sudo installer -pkg XQuartz.pkg -target "/" -verboseR | awk '/installer:%/ { print; }'`, and it prints out only those lines with a numbered percentage as it comes. However, I want to capture the integer part of the percentage and spit it out in a formatted way, i.e. for a percentage of `9.21`, I want to print out `Value: 9`. I am unable to do that..

Comment: Okay, I made it work by making awk choose multiple delimiters, in this case `%` and `.`, and then printing out `$2`.

Answer (score 1):

Sending <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to a running process in Terminal will request the 'status' of that process. This is a hold-over from early BSD and is cross-compatible with most shells (bash, csh, etc.).

A more in-depth conversation with an eye towards Apple specifically can be found [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110810112318227).

Comment: Sorry I did not understand you. How can I "send" `^+T` to a command in a shell script?

Comment: With [redirection](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html). You'll want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063765/get-pid-in-shell-bash) and [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) to get started.

Comment: Addendum: I may have misunderstood. If you're sitting looking at a terminal waiting for something to happen, type control and T (together) on the keyboard to get its status.

Comment: That was very interesting. But not applicable in my problem..